# Convert string to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

I need to convert this into a timespan:

- 8
- 8.3
- 8.15

When I do it like so:

```
DateTime s = booking.TourStartDate.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(booking.TourStartTime.Replace(".", ":")));
```

It will end up adding say '10' (10am) into days rather than the time that it is, albeit in a stupid format that it is.

Comment: the units are in time 8 is 8hours (8am) and after the dot is minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it the straightforward way:

```
static Regex myTimePattern = new Regex( @"^(\d+)(\.(\d+))?$") ;
static TimeSpan MyString2Timespan( string s )
{
  if ( s == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("s") ;
  Match m = myTimePattern.Match(s) ;
  if ( ! m.Success ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("s") ;
  string hh = m.Groups[1].Value ;
  string mm = m.Groups[3].Value.PadRight(2,'0') ;
  int hours   = int.Parse( hh ) ;
  int minutes = int.Parse( mm ) ;
  if ( minutes < 0 || minutes > 59 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("s") ;
  TimeSpan value = new TimeSpan(hours , minutes , 0 ) ;
  return value ;
}
```

Comment: i want to add 3:52 PM in my column having datatype time

Comment: @Rush.2707: once you have a TimeSpan, adding (or subtracting) periods of time is...easy: 1TimeSpan t1 = getMeSomeTime() ; TimeSpan t2 = t1.AddHours(15).AddMinutes(52);` If you have a `DateTime` value, its `Date` property will give you a `DateTime` value with its time components zeroed out to start-of-day, so `DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(15).AddMinutes(52)` will give you today's date with the time set to 3:52pm.

Answer (score 11):

You could try the following:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("0:0", @"h\:m",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

top of my head something like

```
string[] time = booking.TourStartTime.Split('.');

int hours = Convert.ToInt32(time[0]);
int minutes = (time.Length == 2) ? Convert.ToInt32(time[1]) : 0;

if(minutes == 3) minutes = 30;

TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0,hours,minutes,0);
```

I'm not sure what your goal is with minutes though.  If you want 8.3 to be 8:30 then what would 8.7 be?  If it's only on 15 minute intervals (15,3,45) you can just do like i did in the example.

Comment: 8.3 comes in as 8:03 when it should be 8:30 ?

Comment: well yeah.  if you need it to be 30 then you'll need some extra logic.   I'll add something

Answer (score 0):

this works for the examples given:

```
double d2 = Convert.ToDouble("8"); //convert to double
string s1 = String.Format("{0:F2}", d2); //convert to a formatted string
int _d = s1.IndexOf('.'); //find index of .
TimeSpan tis = new TimeSpan(0, Convert.ToInt16(s1.Substring(0, _d)), Convert.ToInt16(s1.Substring(_d + 1)), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the formats that you need.

```
var formats = new[] { "%h","h\\.m" };
var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Test to prove it works:

```
var values = new[] { "8", "8.3", "8.15" };
var formats = new[] { "%h","h\\.m" };

foreach (var value in values)
{
    var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Debug.WriteLine(ts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my example i wanted to convert strings like 1d1h1m or 1h using powershell.

Using the suggestion of using System.Xml.XmlConvert, this handled most situations but required an extra P & T character which can be forgotten.

I was able to find the following solution:

```
$TestStrings = @(
    '1D0h',
    '1M',
    '3d'
    )
foreach ($str in $TestStrings)
{
    [system.xml.xmlconvert]::ToTimeSpan(($str -replace '^(\d)','P$1' -replace '(P\d+d)(\d+)','$1T$2' -replace 'P(\d+)(h|m|s)','PT$1$2').ToUpper()).Tostring()
}
```

Output:

```
1.00:00:00
00:01:00
3.00:00:00
```