# Convert string to time span

Tags: c#

I need to convert my string to time span in c#, Here is my string `52:13:27.0000000`
When I am trying Timespan.parse it is giving error

> The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric
>   components is out of range or contains too many digits.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: did you tried something?

Comment: Is that the only string you're trying to parse or do you actually have a whole bunch? If the latter, what do they look like?

Answer (score 11):

`TimeSpan.Parse()` accepts `Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Miliseconds` if you want to have more than 24 hours, you have to add a day.

In your specific case, it should be something like the following:

```
TimeSpan.Parse("2:04:13:27.0000000");
```

Comment: That seems like a "chicken or the egg" problem.

Comment: This answers explains the error, if you need alternative implementation - adopt code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682099/convert-string-to-timespan to you needs.

Comment: you can pass the values of hour to timespan to convert the same to days instead of calculating manually check my answer

Comment: For this answer to work the OP need to parse his string **somehow** to determine what the first element is and to convert it to the `Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds` format. This hasn't solve the OP's problem, just made it different. Can you provide an answer that takes him all the way?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is convert the hours into days by doing:

```
string x = "52:13:27.000";
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(int.Parse(x.Split(':')[0]),    // hours
                       int.Parse(x.Split(':')[1]),    // minutes
                       int.Parse(x.Split(':')[2].Split('.')[0] )   // seconds
                       );
```

**Desired Output:**

[image]

Comment: Assuming that the OP's string format is consistent. That's why I asked him about it. Nevertheless, this is probably right.

Answer (score 0):

> Timespan.parse is giving error because it takes can't take

```
 hours>23
 minutes>59
 seconds>59
 /*Parsing string format with above conditions  "hh:mm:ss:miliseconds"*/
 Timespan.parse("hh:mm:ss:miliseconds");
```

in this format you won't get Exception

## Or Use It

```
string str = "52:13:27.0000000";
int hours = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(0,2));
int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(3, 2));
int seconds =  Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(6, 2));
string miliseconds= (str.Substring(str.IndexOf('.')+1,str.Length-str.IndexOf('.')-1));
TimeSpan sp = TimeSpan.FromHours(hours);
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.Parse(sp .Days+ ":"+sp.Hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+"."+
miliseconds);
```

Comment: This isn't the answer to the OP's question. It's the reason why his current approach isn't working, but not how to get past it.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for your concern. but if he/she keeps above things in mind problem will be solve

Comment: if we know the reason problem will not come.

Comment: No, the problem is "I need to convert my string to time span in c#" and not "why isn't my code working". To answer this question you need to show how to do it, not why it doesn't work.